# Formik initial values from redux store

Tags: reactjs, formik

i gain values for formik initialValues from redux store, but they're undefined on component mount.

raw example

```
const value1 = useSelector(state => state.store.value1)

const initialValues = { value1 }

const formik = useFormik({ initialValues })

...

return (
 <>
   <input name='value1' value={formik.values.value1} />
 </>
)
```

is there any way to make dependencies on this value ? or load them dinamically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the initial values in Formik by passing the props value of the Redux state.

```
const { user } = this.props; 

return ( 
  <Formik 
    enableReinitialize={true} 
    initialValues={{
      name: user.name ? user.name : "",
      age: user.age ? user.age : ""
   }} 
  > ... 
 </Formik>
)
```